# iTunes want to remove my existing apps on iPad

Tags: itunes, ipad

Here is the situation. I connected my iPad to some new PC, Synced, then ticking Sync Apps from Devices->Apps will give me warning that all existing apps on my iPad will be replaced with those from Library->Apps. But in Library I have just couple old apps, which long time ago I used. So how I can sync the library in iTunes with my existing apps from iPad?

EDIT: **I have tried to click on Transfer Purchases, but not all of the items went to the library, just few of them.**

Comment: possible duplicate: http://superuser.com/questions/102043/sync-iphone-apps-with-itunes-without-deleting-them/188339#188339

Comment: clicking Transfer Purchases does NOT bring all items from iPad to iTunes library, just few of them.

Comment: Perhaps you can emphasize this in your question @Michael

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you registered on the new PC with the same iTunes account you used to purchase the iPad apps?
Can you copy your iTunes library file to the new PC?

The iPad will look to sync to the same library it used before. If it does not find that library it will not allow you to bring the content down to iTunes unless it finds the same library it synced from to begin with.